# How to get TCP-Timestamp (TSval) using python

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy

I've searched in several places, but I didn't find a simple answer to this question -
I have a .pcap file, generated using Wireshark, with several packets in it, and I wish to extract from each packet it's TCP-Timestamp (TSval).
I've managed to open each packet using scapy

```
packets = rdpcap('pcap_file.pcap')
for packet in packets:
    print(packet.payload.id)
```

but I can't find the TSval of the packet (even though I can see the TSval field in the packet when I open it with Wireshark as shown in the picture below).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packets can be accessed like dictionaries whose keys are protocols and values are payloads.  For instance you can print the TCP payload in a packet like this:

```py
if TCP in packet:
   packet[TCP].show()
```

Now to get the `TSval` of the payload you have to look in TCP options.  Each TCP option is encoded by scapy as a couple `(option name, option value)`.  For the timestamp option, the option value is itself a couple `(TSval, TSecr)`.  So you can basically get what you want doing the following:

```py
from scapy.all import TCP, rdpcap

packets = rdpcap('packets.pcapng')
for packet in packets:
    if TCP in packet:  #  ignore packets without TCP payload
        for opt, val in packet[TCP].options:  #  consider all TCP options
            if opt == 'Timestamp':
                TSval, TSecr = val  #  decode the value of the option
                print('TSval =', TSval)
```

Comment: They're not really dictionaries, they just partially act as such